# What does "put the imprimatur of the State itself on an exclusion" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Many who deem same-sex marriage to be wrong reach that conclusion based on decent and honorable religious or philosophical premises, and neither they nor their beliefs are disparaged here. But when that sincere, personal opposition becomes enacted law and public policy, the necessary consequence is to **put the imprimatur of the State itself on an exclusion** that soon demeans or stigmatizes those whose own liberty is then denied.

Does "put the imprimatur of the State itself on an exclusion" mean "the State approves of excluding the gay marriage" or "exclude the State from approving of gay marriage"? What confuses me specifically is the definition of "exclusion" here.

Comment: What's causing you difficulty here? Is it the definition of "imprimatur"? The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=imprimatur) defines it as "A mark of official approval." So the bolded section could be rephrased as "the necessary consequence is to put the mark of official approval of the State itself on an exclusion." Does that make sense to you, or are you  confused about the grammar of this sentence?

Comment: Thx for your response. What confused me is the definition of "exclusion".

Comment: The exclusion is the preventing someone from marrying another person of the same sex. So the statement means "When the state approves removing the right of marriage from people on the basis of their sexual orientation that degrades those people.

Comment: This is from the majority opinion in *Obergefell v Hodges*, the US Supreme Court decision on marriage equality. Good for you. I hope you read the whole thing' It's a ringing endorsement of equality before the law

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, @deadrat; it's been very helpful.

Comment: I think what confuses you (certainly what confused me up until I just re-parsed the sentence correctly now) is the meaning of ‘put’, actually. Maybe it's just me, but I couldn't make the sentence make any sense either because I read it as a phrasal verb, _put [sth.] on an exclusion_, which made no sense. The actual meaning is ‘put/set the State’s stamp of approval down upon such an exclusion’.

Comment: Yeah,you are right Janus Bahs Jacquet. I had been trying to make sense of  _put [sth.] on an exclusion_  up until  I read @deadrat's explanation. Your reply is of great help. Thx.

Comment: A prohibition against performing same-sex marriages results in an exclusion from the benefits afforded to married couples, and this exclusion is the issue that tends to frame much of the debate. An exclusion is a prohibition from belonging. Exclusions tend to relate to membership status (such as being married), whereas a prohibition usually pertains more to a specific event or action. The distinction is legalistic, but some states that prohibit performing same-sex marriages will recognize couples married in other states, so the distinction is of practical importance.

Comment: BTW, please provide the source of the quote. This site is fussy about such matters.

Comment: The source of the quote: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/acts-of-faith/wp/2015/06/26/here-are-the-key-excerpts-on-religious-liberty-from-the-supreme-courts-decision-on-gay-marriage/

Answer (score 3):

Originally, an *imprimatur* (Latin for "let it be printed") was official permission from the Catholic Church to print a book.

Since then, the word has come to mean official approval generally.  In this case, the writer is saying that for the government to forbid same-sex marriage is to (effectively) give official approval to homophobia.

Comment: Thx for your response, Malvolio. could U explain the meaning of "exclusion" here in the context?

Comment: "Exclusion" in context refers specifically excluding same-sex marriage from the greater category of legal marriage, but metaphorically, the author was hinting at exclusion of homosexuals and homosexuality from society.